# Multiple assignments to a folder variable

Tags: vba, outlook

it is possible to assign a Folder variable of this type:

```
Dim FldrDest As Folder

Set FldrDest = Session.Folders("user@email.it").Folders("Folder").Folders("SubFolder").Folders("SubFolder").Folders("SubFolder")
```

a string autocompiled by a loop like this?

```
Dim CartellaDestinazioneSplit As String

'generated by a loop
CartellaDestinazioneSplit  = "Session.Folders("user@email.it").Folders("Folder").Folders("SubFolder").Folders("SubFolder").Folders("SubFolder")"

Set FldrDest = CartellaDestinazioneSplit
```

Thank you

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Is this a question or a statement? If the former, can you please clarify exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No. In the latter case you have a string that looks like VBA code. You cannot execute it, it is still a string no matter what it looks like.

If you want a function that returns a folder by its `"\"` separated path, try something like the following:

```
Function GetOutlookFolderByPath(ByVal path As String) As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim folders As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    ' Split the path
    folders = Split(path, "\")

    ' Start at root
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olFolder = Session.Folders(folders(0))
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' If the root folder doesn't exist, return nothing
    If olFolder Is Nothing Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Loop through the rest of the folders in the path
    For i = 1 To UBound(folders)
        Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders(folders(i))
        If olFolder Is Nothing Then
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    ' Return the folder
    Set GetOutlookFolderByPath = olFolder

    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    ' Handle any errors here, e.g., print to Immediate Window
    Debug.Print "Error retrieving folder: " & Err.Description
End Function
```

Comment: If the reply answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!